# Where do I fill the App Showdown Participation Details?

Tags: application-development

I never submitted an app to the Ubuntu Software Center.
Where do I fill [this info](http://developer.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Ubuntu-App-Showdown-Participation-Details.txt)? In the PPA? In a form in the USC?...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit your application via https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/ you can add the contents of the text file there.